# JScrollPane on dynamic filled JPanel with null layout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

i want a scrollpane on my GUI. The area, i want to have "scrollable" is a JPanel without any LayoutManager, because the content is something between static and dynamic... but maybe a part of my code will help

Here it is:

```
pane = getContentPane();

    jpane = new JPanel();
//  jpane.setBounds(0, 75, 680, 255);
    jpane.setLayout(null);

    jsp = new JScrollPane(jpane, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    jsp.setBounds(0, 75, 680, 255);
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680,255));
pane.add(jsp);
```

My JPanel will be filled with this piece of code...

```
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(spaltenzahl.getText()); i++) {
        JTextField spaltennamen_feld = new JTextField();
        spaltennamen_feld.setBounds(10, 10+35*i, 150, 25);
        spaltennamen_arraylist.add(spaltennamen_feld);

        JComboBox<String> datentypen_box = new JComboBox<String>(types);
        datentypen_box.setBounds(170, 10+35*i, 150, 25);
        datentypen_arraylist.add(datentypen_box);

        JComboBox<String> datenzusatz_box = new JComboBox<String>(comb);
        datenzusatz_box.setBounds(330, 10+35*i, 100, 25);
        datenzusatz_arraylist.add(datenzusatz_box);

        jpane.add(spaltennamen_feld);
        jpane.add(datentypen_box);
        jpane.add(datenzusatz_box);
    }
```

Problem: i can't add a screenshot of my GUI, cause of missing ehr... i forgot the name of this required things here ^_^
But i the real problem is: overflowing content won't be displayed on my JPanel and my ScrollPane does not scroll. Any idea?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: `"...but maybe a part of my code will help..."` -- what you want to create and post is a [minimal, complete, valid example or MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can test and modify appropriate code. Also, please explain more the need for null layouts, as you're usually *far* better off avoiding these things, as you're finding out, since for one, they don't play nice with JScrollPanes. I'm betting that your feeling like you need to use a null layout is really an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise.

Comment: The problem is the `null` layout.  The `JScrollPane` relies on the information provided by the layout manager to make determination about when to show scroll bars. *"is a JPanel without any LayoutManager, because the content is something between static and dynamic"* is irrlevent.  I have plenty of UI's that are dynamic and changing all the times, that doesn't mean you should discard the use of layout managers. The main reason is, as you have found out, the Swing API relies heavily on their use and the information they provide...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: great minds think alike!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "I have to use a `null` because..." - Insert "red rag to a bull".  Want me to explode. Use `null` and layout in the same sentence ;)

Comment: give some more information about the contents of the panel please
but basically you do the following , add stuff to the panel , wrap panel in scrollpanel , IF you added more stuff OR changed you need to call revalidate() / repaint()

Comment: Yeah, umh... i have a static number of columns the user can fill up, but the user can change the number of rows. 

@fadytaher i'm calling repaint() and revalidate() directly after the loop

Comment: @just_do_IT: please check out the edit to my answer. Try running the code and seeing what it can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is none of the above. I think that you want to use a JTable, one with three columns, the last two whose editor is a JComboBox.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Foo2 {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      String[] columns = {"Spaltennamen", " Datentypen", "Datenzusatz"};
      String[] dataStrings1 = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
      String[] dataStrings2 = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
      Random random = new Random();

      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
      int spaltenzahl = 10;  // this can change
      for (int i = 0; i < spaltenzahl; i++) {
         Vector<String> rowData = new Vector<>();
         rowData.add("Row Number " + (i + 1));
         rowData.add(dataStrings1[random.nextInt(dataStrings1.length)]);
         rowData.add(dataStrings2[random.nextInt(dataStrings2.length)]);
         model.addRow(rowData);
      }

      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      table.getColumn(columns[1]).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(dataStrings1)));
      table.getColumn(columns[2]).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(dataStrings2)));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);


      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```